# Getting Error Code: 1055. from a MySQL query even when I use ANY_VALUE()

Tags: mysql

I have the tables and data to reproduce the error:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `theway`;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `theway`
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
    DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

USE `theway`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fault;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fault (
    shorthand    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    score        TINYINT NOT NULL -- 0 to 255
);

INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('PARTY', 'Party with alcohol', 60);
INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('WORK', 'Skip minimum 6 hour workday', 50);
INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('SMOKE', 'Smoke', 50);
INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('COFFEE', 'Coffee / Caffeine', 20);
INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('FOOD', 'Crap food', 15);
INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('ROUTINE', 'Skip daily routines', 15);
INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('WORKOUT', 'Skip workout', 15);
INSERT INTO fault (shorthand, title, score)
VALUES ('SLEEP', 'Oversleep to exhaustion', 10);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS day;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS day (
    date         DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    hours_worked TINYINT NOT NULL,
    note         VARCHAR(1028) NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS day_has_fault;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS day_has_fault (
    day_date         DATE NOT NULL,
    fault_shorthand  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (day_date, fault_shorthand)
);

ALTER TABLE day_has_fault ADD CONSTRAINT fk__day_has_fault__day__day_date FOREIGN KEY (day_date) REFERENCES day (date);
ALTER TABLE day_has_fault ADD CONSTRAINT fk__day_has_fault__fault__fault_shorthand FOREIGN KEY (fault_shorthand) REFERENCES fault (shorthand);

INSERT INTO day (date, hours_worked, note)
VALUES ('2019-04-20', 4, 'Just some regular day.');
INSERT INTO day_has_fault (day_date, fault_shorthand)
VALUES ('2019-04-20', 'SLEEP');
INSERT INTO day_has_fault (day_date, fault_shorthand)
VALUES ('2019-04-20', 'WORK');
INSERT INTO day_has_fault (day_date, fault_shorthand)
VALUES ('2019-04-20', 'ROUTINE');

INSERT INTO day (date, hours_worked, note)
VALUES ('2019-04-21', 6, 'Atleast did 6 hours minimum.');
INSERT INTO day_has_fault (day_date, fault_shorthand)
VALUES ('2019-04-21', 'SLEEP');
INSERT INTO day_has_fault (day_date, fault_shorthand)
VALUES ('2019-04-21', 'WORKOUT');
INSERT INTO day_has_fault (day_date, fault_shorthand)
VALUES ('2019-04-21', 'FOOD');

INSERT INTO day (date, hours_worked, note)
VALUES ('2019-04-22', 2, 'Only two hours here.');
INSERT INTO day_has_fault (day_date, fault_shorthand)
VALUES ('2019-04-22', 'WORK');

INSERT INTO day (date, hours_worked, note)
VALUES ('2019-04-23', 12, '12 hours work awesome.');
```

And the first query without errors:

```
SELECT
    day.date,
    day.hours_worked,
    day.note,
    day_has_fault.fault_shorthand,
    fault.score
FROM day
LEFT JOIN day_has_fault
    ON day_has_fault.day_date = day.date
LEFT JOIN fault
    ON fault.shorthand = day_has_fault.fault_shorthand;
```

When I add sum and group by I get the error:

```
SELECT
    day.date,
    day.hours_worked,
    day.note,
    day_has_fault.fault_shorthand,
    fault.score,
    sum(fault.score) as fault_sum
FROM day
LEFT JOIN day_has_fault
    ON day_has_fault.day_date = day.date
LEFT JOIN fault
    ON fault.shorthand = day_has_fault.fault_shorthand
GROUP BY day.date;
```

This is the entire error response:

```
Error Code: 1055. Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'theway.day_has_fault.fault_shorthand' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have tried to use ANY_VALUE() on day.hours_worked and day.note, but that did not do much.

Comment: You have to group by all the non-aggregate columns in the select list, but you are only grouping by one of those columns, day.date.

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of your initial query can be grouped by:

```
day.date, day.hours_worked, day.note
```

but not by

```
day_has_fault.fault_shorthand, fault.score
```

because you are summing over `fault.score`, so do this:

```
SELECT
    day.date,
    day.hours_worked,
    day.note,
    sum(fault.score) as fault_sum
FROM day
LEFT JOIN day_has_fault
    ON day_has_fault.day_date = day.date
LEFT JOIN fault
    ON fault.shorthand = day_has_fault.fault_shorthand
GROUP BY day.date,
    day.hours_worked,
    day.note;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4or8L118Z9PCWZBuGACied/1).
And the results are:

```
| date       | hours_worked | note                         | fault_sum |
| ---------- | ------------ | ---------------------------- | --------- |
| 2019-04-20 | 4            | Just some regular day.       | 75        |
| 2019-04-21 | 6            | Atleast did 6 hours minimum. | 40        |
| 2019-04-22 | 2            | Only two hours here.         | 50        |
| 2019-04-23 | 12           | 12 hours work awesome.       |           |
```

You can use [`any_value()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) like this:

```
SELECT
    day.date,
    day.hours_worked,
    day.note,
    any_value(day_has_fault.fault_shorthand) fault_shorthand,
    any_value(fault.score) score,
    sum(fault.score) as fault_sum
FROM day
LEFT JOIN day_has_fault
    ON day_has_fault.day_date = day.date
LEFT JOIN fault
    ON fault.shorthand = day_has_fault.fault_shorthand
GROUP BY day.date;
```

and get unpredictable results for the columns `fault_shorthand` and `score`, like:

```
| date       | hours_worked | note                         | fault_shorthand | score | fault_sum |
| ---------- | ------------ | ---------------------------- | --------------- | ----- | --------- |
| 2019-04-20 | 4            | Just some regular day.       | ROUTINE         | 15    | 75        |
| 2019-04-21 | 6            | Atleast did 6 hours minimum. | FOOD            | 15    | 40        |
| 2019-04-22 | 2            | Only two hours here.         | WORK            | 50    | 50        |
| 2019-04-23 | 12           | 12 hours work awesome.       |                 |       |           |
```

**Edit**
You can get grouped comma separated the values of `fault.shorthand` with [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT
    day.date,
    day.hours_worked,
    day.note,
    sum(fault.score) as fault_sum,
    group_concat(fault.shorthand) shorthand
FROM day
LEFT JOIN day_has_fault
    ON day_has_fault.day_date = day.date
LEFT JOIN fault
    ON fault.shorthand = day_has_fault.fault_shorthand
GROUP BY day.date,
    day.hours_worked,
    day.note;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4or8L118Z9PCWZBuGACied/2).

Comment: Is there a way to also get all the fault_shorthand that a day has in an array format ish way? Maybe using json aggregate or something else?

Comment: I tried to use JSON_ARRAYAGG() in the same way as it is exampled here but it did not work, how come?: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Nevermind it was because of the MySQL version :) Thanks!